# Access nested form fields in view (Embed a Collection of Forms)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I try to build a huge form in symfony 3 with the use of the `CollectionType`. I have to define multiple sub-forms, some multiple, some single.

This is my FormType for that:

```
public function buildRegistrationForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('userRegistration', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => UserRegistrationType::class,
        'entry_options' => ['label' => true],
    ]);
    $builder->add('meters', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => MeterType::class,
        'entry_options' => ['label' => true],
        'allow_add' => true,
    ]);
    ...
}
```

Now I try to access the CollectionType fields in the view. The code for this is:

```
{{ form_label(registrationForm.email, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'form-label'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(registrationForm.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

but I get the error:

```
Neither the property "email" nor one of the methods "email()", "getemail()"/"isemail()"/"hasemail()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".
```

I know that Symfony tries to get the email field directly out of the main form (`registrationForm`), but I don't know how to access the subform. In the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) it is described that I can simply access the sub form by using `registrationForm.userRegistration.email`. But this gives me the error:

```
Neither the property "userRegistration" nor one of the methods ...
```

How can I access the subfields in the view?

Answer (score 0):

1. First step is to understand why we want to use collectionType? 
   In case if you have One-To-Many or Many-To-Many relationship you should use CollectionType. 
   Example:

   ```
   /**
    * Class Team
    *
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="example_project_team")
    */
   class Team
   {

       // ... 

       /**
        * Unidirectional Many-To-Many
        *
        * Many Teams has many users accounts.
        *
        * @var ArrayCollection $users
        *
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(
        *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User",
        *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
        *     orphanRemoval=true
        *     )
        *
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="teams_to_users",
        *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
        *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
        *      )
        */
       protected $users;

        // ...

   }
   ```

In this example we have some entity called team. Each team has many users (this is just example related to you). I guess, you have already created User entity.

2. Imagine that for you have UserRegistrationType for your user entity.

   ```
   /**
    * Class UserRegistrationType
    */
   class UserRegistrationType extends AbstractType
   {
       /**
        * @param FormBuilderInterface  $builder
        * @param array                 $options
        */
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           $builder
               ->add('username', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType', [
                   'label'                 => false,
                   'translation_domain'    => 'messages'
               ])
               ->add('email', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType', [
                   'label'                 => false,
                   'translation_domain'    => 'messages'
               ])

               // ... the other fields

           ;
       }

       /**
        * @return string
        */
       public function getName()
       {
           return 'app_user_registration_type';
       }

       /**
        * @return null|string
        */
       public function getBlockPrefix()
       {
           return 'app_user_registration';
       }

       /**
        * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
        */
       public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
       {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array(
               'data_class'            => User::class,
               'csrf_protection'       => true,
               'validation'            => true,
           ));
       }
   }
   ```

   **Please pay attention** !!!
   We used here `'data_class' => User::class,`
   As you can see we use User object in userRegistrationType. It means, that we can use this form for every object, which has field of type User or field with type CollectionType (your case!) but collection of Users!
   Our Team entity has field users.
3. Now, as we have already created the userRegistrationType we can add it to TeamFormType.

   ```
   public function teamRegistrationFormType(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
       $builder->add('users', CollectionType::class, [
           'entry_type' => UserRegistrationType::class,
               'entry_options' => [
                   'label' => false,
               ],
               'label'         => false,
               'allow_add'     => true,
               'allow_delete'  => true,
               'by_reference'  => false,
       ]);

       // ...

   }
   ```
4. Finally. Your form in twig:

   ```
   {# you can add this form in your twig file #}
   <div class="box">
       {% block team_form %}
       {{ form_start(team_form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role' : 'form'}}) }}
       <div class="box-body">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       {% block users_collection %}
                           <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                               {{ 'admin.label.phones'|trans  }}
                           </label>
                           <div class="col-sm-10 users" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(team_form.users.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                               {% for user in users %}
                                   <div>
                                       {{ form_widget(user) }}
                                   </div>
                               {% endfor %}
                           </div>
                           <span class="help-block">
                               {{ form_errors(users) }}
                           </span>
                       {% endblock users_collection %}
                   </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                           {{ 'admin.button.submit'|trans }}
                       </button>
                   </div>
               </div>
               {{ form_end(team_form) }}
       </div>
       {% endblock team_form %}
   </div>
   ```
5. Here we have strange widget `{{ form_widget(user) }}`. I guess, you want to edit the style of this widget. You can do it with Symfony built-in form styles. Create file (if you haven't created it yet) `path_to_your_project/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig` and add to it the style of your userRegistrationType. Notice, that name of this widget is created from name of you form block prefix and string  "_widget" (`public function getBlockPrefix()`)

   ```
   {% file fields.html.twig %}
   {% trans_default_domain 'messages' %}

   {% block app_user_registration_widget %}
       {% spaceless %}
           <div class="form-group" {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                   {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' }}) }}
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' }}) }}
               </div>
           </div>
       {% endspaceless %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```
6. And of course you will have to set the add and delete buttons. For this purposes I suggest you use official documentation: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) or you can use bundle (but not official): [ninsuo/symfony-collection](https://packagist.org/packages/ninsuo/symfony-collection)